# QML Camera não fica FULL SCREEN

Tags: qt, qml

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que necessita que a câmera frontal ocupe toda a tela de fundo, estilo o aplicativo snapchat, mas utilizando QML a câmera com espaçamento em cima e em baixo da câmera. QML Responsável pela câmera:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    id: item1
    width: 720
    height: 1080

    property alias camera: camera
    property alias video: video

    Camera {
        id: camera

        imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

        flash.mode: Camera.FlashRedEyeReduction

    }

    VideoOutput {
        id : video
        anchors.fill: parent

        orientation: -90
        source: camera
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
    }

}
```

Comment: O `Item` onde você está colocando a câmera tem 720x1080px. É essa a proporção da imagem da câmera?

Comment: O Item tem sim, e a resolução da tela do aparelho celular é de 720x1080

Comment: Tente `fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop` dentro do `VideoOutput`.

Answer (score 1):

Boas!

Sendo que o item pai tem  1080*720 se queres a camera esticada a esta resolução falta o fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch

```
VideoOutput {
    id : video
    anchors.fill: parent
    //Adiciona isto...
    fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
    orientation: -90
    source: camera
    focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
}
```